# How to check the text mode

Tags: pdftex, accents

I need to check that during symbol replacement the mode is really text. This came from such task:
I do replace underdot symbols like ạ to avoid in pdflatex errors like "`Unicode char \u8:ạ not set up for use with LaTeX`". The text is like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1EA1}{\d{a}}

\begin{document}

ạ   

\end{document}
```

I want to have more correct text with no possible bad situations:

1) but I don't know how to check the text mode

2) `ifmmode` can be used but I don't know how to simply replace underdot symbols in math mode.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 4):

For an “underdot” accent in math mode, use the `accents` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,accents}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1EA1}{%
  \ifmmode
    \underaccent{\dot}{a}%
  \else
    \d{a}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

ạ $ạ$

\end{document}
```

However, I'd avoid using `ạ` in math mode for this, as “a with an under dot accent” is conceptually different from the character LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DOT BELOW.

[image]

If you load the `fixltx2e` package (which will be the default with TeX Live 2015 or MiKTeX when LaTeX version 2015/01/01 is used), you can simplify the code by using `\TextOrMath`:

```
%\RequirePackage{fixltx2e} % needed only for LaTeX prior to 2015/01/01

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,accents}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1EA1}{%
  \TextOrMath{\d{a}}{\underaccent{\dot}{a}}%
}

\begin{document}

ạ $ạ$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Egreg. And why you think second variant preferable?

Comment: @vmk The `\TextOrMath` is surely preferable as it is more robust and simpler.

Comment: @egreg I looked up `\TextOrMath` and found that it essentially does `\ifmmode #2\else #1\fi`, but it is e-TeX protected, even though all contents are fully expandable.  Could you explain why it is still protected?

Comment: @HenriMenke For instance, if you do `\ifmmode MATH\else TEXT\fi` in a cell of an `array`, you get quite a surprising result. The protection (either with \DeclareRobustCommand` or `\protected\def`) avoids the issue. Not really important in this case, because Unicode characters beyond ASCII have their own protection mechanism.